# "Edit in Emacs..." input manager for OSX

Tags: macos, emacs

Is there anything like the [input manager for TextMate](http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html) (at the very end of the page) which allows to edit from any Cocoa text edit controls in TextMate? It basically installs a menu "Edit in TextMate...". I tried to search for it, but I have not find anything. I think it would be very nice to have such a feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it (I keep meaning to), but [QuickCursor](http://github.com/jessegrosjean/quickcursor) is supposed to do that (for any editor, not just Emacs).

As noted in the comment, this requires ODB support, for which [EditorClient](http://github.com/robtillotson/EditorClient) can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. QuickCursor does not support emacs - it seems to only support editors that implements the ODB (http://www.barebones.com/support/develop/odbsuite.html) protocol. Also it does not work all the time - it uses the accessibility API and in cases like mail.app / safari / ... it wont work right now.

Comment: Another project, EditorClient (http://github.com/robtillotson/EditorClient), implements the ODB protocol and hands it off to a command line program.  I've been using it for a while with Emacs.  So I guess between the two you can maybe get what you want.  I have added this to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aquamacs just added ODB support.  You should be able to try it in a [nightly build](http://aquamacs.org/nightlies.shtml).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of one, but it should be fairly straightforward to hack one.  You'd simply want to call emacslient with the path.